# Choosing a random number

Tags: statistics, expectation, word-problem

A radio show conducts a game according to the following rules. A number between $1$ and $100$ is selected at random, and the DJ announces what number is chosen. Call it $n$. The announcer then randomly selects a number between $1$ and $n$ and asks that the first called guess the value of the second number chosen. Assuming that the caller's guess is equally likely to be any number between $1$ and $n$, determine the expected value of the number guessed by the caller.

Do I need to use discrete expected value formula? Or there is a certain method to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$\text{If the set }A_i\text{ are mutually exclusive events (}A_i\cap A_j = \emptyset\ \forall i\neq j)$$
$$\text{ such that }P\big(\bigcup_i A_i) = \sum_iP(A) = 1\text{, then}$$
$$E[X] = E[X|\Omega] = E\big[X|\bigcup_i A_i] = \sum_iE[X|A_i]\cdot P(A_i)$$

If you let the event $A_n$ represent that the first draw resulted in the number $n$,
can you find $P(A_n)$, $E[X|A_n]$?

---

EDIT: (in response to OP comments)
It should be clear that the probability of any $n$ on the first draw should be the same for all $n$. So $P(A_n) = \frac1{100},\ \forall n$.
Now, the question becomes: what is the expected value of the second number, $k$, given that the first number is $n$? Well, if we have fixed $n$, the probability of the second number should be $\frac1n$ for all $k$ values. Using this:
$$E[k|A_n] = \sum_{k=1}^{n}k\cdot P(k) = \frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n k$$
Now, taking in the equation from above:
$$E[k] = \sum_{n=1}^{100} E[k|A_n]\cdot P(A_n) = \frac1{100}\sum_{n=1}^{100}\frac{n+1}{2} = \ ...$$

Comment: @DaryaChenskikh, I gave a very high level response. Let me know if confusion still remains, I think you'll find this problem simpler than expected

Comment: As long as we're teasing this along, the hint from @jameselmore leads to the
sum of the first 100 integers divided by 200. Now for the variance?

Comment: @BruceTrumbo, are you extending the scope of the problem? Not certain where variance comes into play with OPs question

Comment: @jameselmore Yes, it is a pretty good hint! But this problem is quit complicated. 1st draw is 1/100 for the range from 1 =< n =< 100 and then second draw is 1/n for range from 1 =< x =< n?

Comment: @DaryaChenskikh, I'm making edits based on your comment